# Numpy how to create mask "3D array contains 1D-value"

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays: 3D-array `ndarray(N,M,3)` and 1D-array `ndarray(3)`. How to create mask N×M by comparing last axis of 3D array with 1D array?

For now, I can do this with:

```
mask = (A[:,:,0] == B[0]) & (A[:,:,1] == B[1]) & (A[:,:,2] == B[2])
```

But there must be a shorter solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mask = (A == B).all(axis=2)`

For more information about how this works, search `numpy broadcasting`.

Comment: Thank you! I spent 20 minutes in search and didn't found solution :) This works. Thank you for reference to numpy broadcasting, I will read it.